# Set a default value instead of the value passed when saving an entity

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using NestJS/TypeORM and I need to seed data in my entities.

I have a table A linked to B and C with ManyToOne relations. One B or C is linked to Many A.

I use DataFactory to generate my seeds, then I add 2 fields in my A entry: idB and idC

```js
      const A = DataFactory.createForClass(A).generate(qty);
```

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      const randB= randomFromArray(B);
      A[i].idB= randB.idB;
      const randC= randomFromArray(C);
      A[i].idC= randC.idC;
    }
```

It works perfectly for C, but for B, the column idB in the A table is always NULL, despite having the correct data sent.

I checked MySQL logs and it appears that MySQL does not receive the idB, because it passes DEFAULT. For idC, it passes the correct data.

I'm quite lost, I checked my A, B and C entities and I couldn't find an error or even a small difference in the relations/models etc.

Entire seeder code:

```js
import { A } from '@Entity/A.entity';
import { BsRepository } from '@Repositories/Bs.repository';
import { CsRepository } from '@Repositories/Cs.repository';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataFactory } from 'nestjs-seeder';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { randomFromArray } from 'utils/fonctions';
import { CSeeder } from './Cs.seeder';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from 'src/app.module';
import { BsSeeder } from './Bs.seeder';


@Injectable()
export class ASeeder {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(A)
    private readonly ARepository: Repository<A>,
    private readonly CRepository: CsRepository,
    private readonly BRepository: BsRepository
  ) {}


  async seed(qty): Promise<any> {
    // Génération des A
    const As =
      DataFactory.createForClass(A).generate(qty);


    // Récupération de tous les Bs et lien aléatoire avec les A
    let Bs = await this.BsRepository.findAll();
    if (Bs.length === 0) {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      const seeder = app.get(BsSeeder);
      await seeder.seed(10);
      await app.close();
    }

//Added this line
    Bs = await this.BsRepository.findAll();


    // Vérification qu'il existe au moins 1 C dans la BDD, sinon création d'un C
    let Cs = await this.CsRepository.findAll();


    if (Cs.length === 0) {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      const seeder = app.get(CSeeder);
      await seeder.seed();
      await app.close();
    }


    Cs = await this.CsRepository.findAll();
    console.log('Cs', randomFromArray(Cs));


    for (let i = 0; i < As.length; i++) {
      const randB = randomFromArray(Bs);
      As[i].idBA = randB.idB;
      const randC = randomFromArray(Cs);
      As[i].idCA = randC.idC;
    }


    console.log('As', As);
    await this.ARepository.save(As);
  }


  async drop(): Promise<any> {
    return this.AsRepository.delete({});
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your "randomFromArray" function? (nevermind)

Comment: Hello, here you go :
```typescript
export function randomFromArray(array) {
  const min = 0;
  const max = array.length - 1;
  const alea = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  const random = array[alea];
  return random;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is because, unlike for C, you don't read B a second time after your "empty check". See comments in code.

```js
//...
@Injectable()
export class ASeeder {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(A)
    private readonly ARepository: Repository<A>,
    private readonly CRepository: CsRepository,
    private readonly BRepository: BsRepository
  ) {}


  async seed(qty): Promise<any> {

    const As =
      DataFactory.createForClass(A).generate(qty);

    //read Bs a first time
    const Bs = await this.BsRepository.findAll();

    //if Bs empty, add value to its repo
    if (Bs.length === 0) {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      const seeder = app.get(BsSeeder);
      await seeder.seed(10);
      await app.close();
    }

    //never reads Bs again


    //reads Cs a first time
    let Cs = await this.CsRepository.findAll();

    //if Cs empty, add value to its repo
    if (Cs.length === 0) {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      const seeder = app.get(CSeeder);
      await seeder.seed();
      await app.close();
    }

    //reads Cs a second time after its populated
    Cs = await this.CsRepository.findAll();
    console.log('Cs', randomFromArray(Cs));


    for (let i = 0; i < As.length; i++) {
      const randB = randomFromArray(Bs);
      As[i].idBA = randB.idB;
      const randC = randomFromArray(Cs);
      As[i].idCA = randC.idC;
    }


    console.log('As', As);
    await this.ARepository.save(As);
  }


  async drop(): Promise<any> {
    return this.AsRepository.delete({});
  }
}
```

Comment: I applied your changes and the idB remains NULL.

Comment: are your steps for B now exactly the same as for C, unlike our code samples?

Comment: yes, I edited the question here so the code is up to date with your advices.

Comment: Are both seeders the same as well? one is called BsSeeder and the other CSeeder (no 's') so there is a little inconsistency here (should not be a problem but maybe there's another typo ?) + for B you call seed(10) while calling seed() for C

Comment: Thanks for your help.

B and C seeders are not the same : C is 'hardcoded' with defined values, B is using DataFactory to generate random values.

Both work perfectly as B and C are seeded. 

Then A receive idB and idC (console.log('As', As); show that the data are complete and correct).

But then the save() function is called, and MYSQL logs show that the value received for C is correct (an id), but idB is DEFAULT. As I don't have a default value, it remains NULL.

BTW, I set this column to be non-nullable and I get no error from nestjs/typeorm.